# Set desktop Flutter to run in maximized size at startup

Tags: flutter, window

How can one set the initial size of the Flutter desktop app to maximized in desktop platforms (Windows, macOS, Linux)?

I know there are window size plugins and we can set size manually, but is there any simple way, like for example `Window.startupSize=WindowSize.Maximized`

There are old issues in Flutter community (https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/39556) but I want to know what is latest update?

Answer (score 5):

For future reference to anyone still facing this issue you can locate this code in the file:

> windows/runner/win32_window.cpp

```
bool Win32Window::Show() {
   return ShowWindow(window_handle_, SW_MAXIMIZE);
}
```

its in line 152 and you can replace **SW_MAXIMIZE** with **SW_MAXIMIZE**

Answer (score 4):

I am also looking into this. Any update on this?

I am currently using this:
https://pub.dev/packages/desktop_window

But I hope Flutter can support this natively..

Answer (score 3):

My solution:

**1. For release (edit win32_window.cpp).**

Find:

```
bool Win32Window::Show() {
  return ShowWindow(window_handle_, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
}
```

Change to:

```
bool Win32Window::Show() {
  return ShowWindow(window_handle_, SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED);
}
```

**2. For debug (edit main.cpp).**

Find:

```
Win32Window::Point origin(10, 10);
Win32Window::Size size(1280, 720);
```

Change to:

```
Win32Window::Point origin(0, 0);
Win32Window::Size size(GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN), GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN));
```

Answer (score 1):

It is platform specific, but on Windows it can be done without plugins.
You must modify the file "windows\runner\win32_window.cpp". In the CreateWindow() function you must add the "WS_MAXIMIZE" option. That is all.

Example:

```
    HWND window = CreateWindow(
        window_class, title.c_str(), 
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE | WS_MAXIMIZE,
        Scale(origin.x, scale_factor), Scale(origin.y, scale_factor),
        Scale(size.width, scale_factor), Scale(size.height, scale_factor),
        nullptr, nullptr, GetModuleHandle(nullptr), this);
```

Comment: While this works in DEBUG mode, there is an issue in the RELEASE mode, see https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/76463

Answer (score 0):

```
bool Win32Window::Show() {
  return ShowWindow(window_handle_, SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED);
}
```

This Work for me on Windows, **but what about macOS and Linux?**

This was good because don't need to add external package like [window_manager](https://pub.dev/packages/window_manager)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).